# Azure Active Directory Single Sign On timeout

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure Active Directory Single Sign On. I want help in following basic questions:

- What is the default session timeout once the user login to the site?
- Currently we are observing the timeout is very short, how can we increase it?

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Is this a site that you've developed yourself? If not, what site is this? Approximately how long is the session duration you're observing?

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on how you secured your site. The most common strategy entails mirroring the validity window of the token used to initiate the session. Assuming you used OpenId Connect, that would be 1 hour.
You can change the default behavior by decoupling the duration of your own session from the validity window of the token. If you are using OWIN middleware, you can pass in the protocol options UseTokenLifetime = false. The same approach will work with both WS-Federation and OpenID Connect middlewares.